# display data from the same database colomn into 2 different jtable colomns using self join

Tags: java, mysql, self-join

I want to display data from the same database colomn into 2 different jtable colomns using that self join from the statement. I'm pretty sure my problem is somewhere here but I don't know how to solve it:

```
    while (rs.next()) {
        String d = rs.getString("a.nrzbor");
        String e = rs.getString("b.nrzbor");
        model.addRow(new Object[]{d, e});
        jTable5.setModel(model);
    }
```

Here is the full code:

```
    String de_la = introducereOras1.getText();
    String la = introducereOras2.getText();
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"nrzbor1", "nrzbor2"}, 0);

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aeroport";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";

    PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try{
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement("SELECT a.nrzbor , b.nrzbor" +
                                    "FROM Zboruri a,Zboruri b\n" +  
                                    "WHERE (a.de_la = ? AND b.de_la = ?) AND (a.la = ? AND b.la = ?);");
        myStmt.setString(1, de_la);
        myStmt.setString(2, la);
        myStmt.setString(3, la);
        myStmt.setString(4, de_la);
        rs = myStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String d = rs.getString("a.nrzbor");
            String e = rs.getString("b.nrzbor");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{d, e});
            jTable5.setModel(model);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What actually happens?  Is there an exception?  There's a `\n` character, missing spaces, and an extra `;` in the query.